# Making ajax request in javascript when cors is not allowed from serverside?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

- Request Using Fetch

```js
function status(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
  }
}

function json(response) {
  return response.json()
}


fetch('https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/+apikey+/autosuggest?q=delhi',{mode: 'no-cors'})
  .then(status)
  .then(json)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
```

**Above code gives error**

> i also tried with the httprequest but it's not working

Comment: _“but it's not working”_ - yeah well that’s because it’s _not supposed to_ … You will need to proxy this request via either your own server (so that from the client-side perspective it isn’t cross-domain any more), or a 3rd-party server that adds the appropriate CORS headers.

Comment: is this `+apikey+` is a mistake here in the description or its there in your code as well?

Comment: @CBroe  if i don't have the server access then how to make the request

Comment: No @SamGhatak apikey is not the mistake

Answer (score 1):

it will not work as you have to enable the cors on your server. However you can use proxy server for this.